# Error en Django corriendo py manage.py test <app>

Tags: python, django, testing, console

Actualmente estoy desarrolando un proyecto personal en Django. En este proyecto tengo mis aplicaciones dentro de una carpeta llamada applications.

Una de mis aplicaciones se llama transactions y dentro de esta tengo un archivo llamado test.py en el que tengo el siguiente código para testear mi Modelo Currency.

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Currency

# Create your tests here.

class CurrencyModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_get_old_date_with_old_date(self):
        """
        get_old_date returns the value of the Representative Market Rate for the specified date
        """

        time1 = datetime(2022,1,1)
        time2 = '2021-01-01'

        cop = Currency.objects.get(code='COP')

        self.assertAlmostEqual(cop.get_old_trm(time1), 3981.16, 1)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(cop.get_old_trm(time2), 3432.50, 1)
```

Al correr en mi carpeta principal este comando `py manage.py test transactions` me genera el siguiente error

```
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: transactions (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: transactions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transactions'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

Al correr este otro comando `py manage.py test applications.transactions` me genera este otro error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 68, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 1044, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 894, in build_suite
    tests = self.load_tests_for_label(label, discover_kwargs)
  File "F:\Documentos\Programación\Projects\fundrivo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 868, in load_tests_for_label
    tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 340, in discover
    self._get_directory_containing_module(top_part)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 354, in _get_directory_containing_module
    full_path = os.path.abspath(module.__file__)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 527, in abspath
    return normpath(_getfullpathname(path))
TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType
```

La verdad no tengo claro qué podría estar pasando. En mi archivo Settings tengo agregada de esta manera mi app (transactions)

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        # Own apps
        'applications.core',
        'applications.users',
        'applications.transactions'
    ]
```

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

```
- Main/
    - applications/
        - transactions/
            - __init.py__
            - admin.py
            - apps.py
            - models.py
            - tests.py
            - urls.py
            - views.py
    - principal/
        - settigns/
            - __init.py__
            - base.py
            - local.py
            - prod.py
        - __init.py__
        - asgi.py
        - urls.py
        - wsgi.py
    - page_templates/
    - static/
    - manage.py
```

Mi archivo de settings es `local.py`

Comment: Hola Juan, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, el problema parece estar en el archivo **loader.py** que no nos muestras... podrías editar tu pregunta  y agregarlo como texto?.

Comment: Gracias Marce! Ya edité la pregunta. En cuanto al archivo loader.py, este hace parte del módulo de unittest que tiene por defecto python 3.9. Crees que deba incluirlo igualmente? Es un código bastante extenso.

Comment: El error parece ser que no encuentra el módulo **transactions**  (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transactions'), yo quería ver donde está el import correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

El error es este:

*ImportError: Failed to import test module: transactions*

Prueba a cambiar:

```
from .models import Currency
```

por esto:

```
from applications.transactions.models import Currency
```

¿sigue fallando?